# python verify AWS S3 canned ACL / get list of valid canned ACLs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, botocore

Is there away to validate a canned AWS S3 ACL or is there a list of valid ACLs in `boto3`/`botocore` available?

[image]

I'd like to verify a user input ACL. I could just compile a list myself to verify against, but I figured it might be somewhere within `boto3` or `botocore`. I've checked, but found nothing.

Comment: I don't think it's available. I also had to use strings. I think it's because boto3 is merely an interface between the AWS API can it passes everything it gets as parameters to the API.

Comment: Thanks @PraneethPeiris ... looks like this is the answer, so if you would like to post it

Comment: Okay, I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's available. I also had to use strings. I think it's because boto3 is merely an interface between the AWS API can it passes everything it gets as parameters to the API.

See the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/acl-overview.html) and boto3 reference [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_acl).